# Particle system physics acting weird

Tags: c++, physics, simulation, particles

My particle system's physics update function seems to be incorrect. I'm aiming for all the particles to be attracted towards the mouse.

The particles move towards the mouse pointer just as expected, until they go very near. When they are near, they speed up so much, that they fly far away from the pointer and never return.

Here's the update function:

```
void updateParticle(particle& p,double time){
    const double G=0.000000000066726;
    const double POINTERMASS=1000000000000;

    double squareDistance=pow(p.coords.x-pointerDevice.x,2)+pow(p.coords.y-pointerDevice.y,2)+pow(p.coords.z-pointerDevice.z,2);
    if(squareDistance<0.001)
        squareDistance=0.001;//to fix the possible division by zero

    coords_3d_f accelerationVector={p.coords.x-pointerDevice.x,p.coords.y-pointerDevice.y,p.coords.z-pointerDevice.z};

    accelerationVector=vector_scalar_multiplication(vector_unit(accelerationVector),((G*POINTERMASS)/squareDistance));
    accelerationVector=vector_scalar_multiplication(accelerationVector,time);

    p.velocity=vector_addition(p.velocity,accelerationVector);

    p.coords.x-=p.velocity.x*time;
    p.coords.y-=p.velocity.y*time;
    p.coords.z-=p.velocity.z*time;
}
```

When the squareDistance is constant, the program looks OK, but I know it's false.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually see the particles speed up, or do they just disappear off-screen? You can try increasing the minimum `squareDistance` until you see them slow down.

Comment: @Staven I see them go for a while with huge speed. Then they disappear.

Comment: If I'm counting right, when a particle is 1 unit away from the pointer, you'll get about 67 units per second squared of acceleration. How long is a unit here, on screen? It might be a good idea to make `POINTERMASS` smaller.

Comment: @Staven One unit is one pixel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force is inversely proportional to the square of the distance, so as the distance approaches 0, force (and acceleration) approach infinity. In other words, if the particles get very close, they also get very fast.

If you want to be physically accurate, make your pointer-object have a finite size, so that particles bounce off of it.

If you don't need to be accurate, you can make the force *decrease* when the particles are very close.

Comment: I do want to be physically very accurate. Could the bug be fixed by making the particles jump over the pointer when they come close enough?

Comment: if you need to be physically super-accurate, then you need to consider that the concept of "center of gravity" is an excellent approximation for most calculations but makes no sense in reality

Comment: @Hassedev Well, you could, but that wouldn't be very physically accurate, would it? ;)

Comment: @Hassedev You could also simply make the particles die ("burn up in the atmosphere" or something) when they get close enough.

Comment: @LieRyan It doesn't have to be 100% realistic, but almost.

Comment: @Hassedev: then you'll need to compromise, **what behavior do you want** for objects that are very near the center of gravity? Should they eventually get suspended at the center of gravity or for the particles to die off or join together into a larger particle or do you have something else in mind? FYI, Angry Birds Space does the former; it's a choice which makes intuitive sense, although not necessarily physically accurate. Having a specific behavior in mind would be helpful to direct the development a practical solution for the system.

Comment: @LieRyan I want them to speed up until they reach the center, and then slow down and start flying back towards the center.

Comment: The code you have above is almost what you're looking for. Assuming that your coordinates are in screen pixels, I'd make that clamp to 0.001 much bigger, like maybe 16.0

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: when particles get in touch with the mouse pointer  `squareDistance` becomes `0` and produces undefined behavior for your particles by `((G*POINTERMASS)/squareDistance)` because dividing by zero is illegal.

This might work better for you:

```
if (squareDistance >= 1.0) // 1.0 is the zero tolerance for your context of pixel distances
{
    // proceed normally
    accelerationVector=vector_scalar_multiplication(vector_unit(accelerationVector),((G*POINTERMASS)/squareDistance));
    accelerationVector=vector_scalar_multiplication(accelerationVector,time);
}
else
{
    // no acceleration
    accelerationVector=/*{0, 0}*/;
}
```

Comment: I fixed that now, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Just avoiding division by 0 won't help much, since the particles still can get almost arbitrarily close to the pointer.

Comment: @Desmond Hume I edited my code in the question. Have a look at it.

Comment: @Hassedev Edited my answer too.

Comment: @Hassedev ..now with a revised zero tolerance.

Comment: @Desmond Hume I added that piece of code in my code, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When your particle gets very close to the mouse pointer the particle is going to have a **very** high velocity. When this velocity is multiplied by the `time` this is when the particle will jump very far away.

You can try to fix this by setting a maximum velocity.

Comment: time is currently 1. Changing it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: have you tried decreasing the time between calls to `updateParticle`?

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the equation of motion involve the integration of a function at finite intervals, and so one can only approximate the function. This give rise to instability in the system. An easy and fast solution is to use a fixed-step *verlet integration*:

```
void integrate(particle& p, double t2, const particle& mouse)
{
  // universal gravitational constant
  const double G = 0.000000000066726;

  // artificial drag
  // set it to 1.0 to not have any drag
  // set it to 0.0 to not have any momentum
  const double drag = 0.99;

  // get direction and distance between the particle and the mouse
  dvec3 dir = p.pos - mouse.pos;
  double dist2 = dot(dir, dir);
  double dist = sqrt(dist2);
  dir /= dist;

  // calculate relative acceleration vector
  dvec3 a = -dir * G * (p.mass + mouse.mass) / dist2;

  // verlet integration
  dvec3 tmp = p.pos;
  p.pos += (p.pos - p.prev_pos) * drag + a * t2;
  p.prev_pos = tmp;
}

void update(particle& p, double elapsed, const particle& mouse, double& accumulator)
{
  // fixed timestep (arbitrary)
  const double timestep = 1.0 / 120.0;
  const double timestep2 = timestep * timestep;

  // "accumulate" time
  accumulator += elapsed;

  // "consume" time
  while(accumulator > timestep)
  {
    // perform integration
    integrate(p, timestep2, mouse);
    accumulator -= timestep;
  }
}
```

Note: It use the [GLM math library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for clarity.